# How to extract tweets containing a specific URL

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to extract 200 tweets containing the URL http://on.fb.me/. I have tried this:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

ckey = 'just some'
csecret = 'secret keys'
atoken = 'you should'
asecret = 'invalidate now'

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self,status):
        print status



auth = OAuthHandler(ckey,csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["http://fb.me"]
```

When I run this code, the cursor keeps on blinking and nothing happens.

Comment: Why would you post your **secret authentication keys** on a public site like this? Please invalidate those and generate new ones.

Comment: Doing an actual search, there aren't many tweets containing that URL. Maybe test with something a bit more common, first?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: i tested that with word 'car' i got many tweets with this. But not with the string 'fb.me'

Comment: Then clearly it's working, but *there aren't many tweets in the stream with that content*. So what exactly is the problem? If you want the *last* 200, you shouldn't be using `StreamListener` which, as the name implies, is for listening to the *current* stream.

Comment: @jonsharpe: can you suggest me some other way to do the same. I was trying to use json and urllib2 but not able to form correct url

Comment: Your choices aren't `tweepy.StreamListener` or write your own API; spend some time reading their docs and see what other functions they offer.